# Flutter widget test fails for InkWell tap

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter

I have a widget test like this, I can find the widget with `actionKey`, but the tapping test fails and `tapped` value is false after `tester.tap(...)`, what is wrong with my test?

```dart
testWidgets('some test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final UniqueKey actionKey = UniqueKey();
  bool tapped = false;

  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: SlidableListItem(
        child: const ListTile(title: Text('item')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            key: actionKey,
            child: const Text('action'),
            onTap: () => tapped = true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ));

  await tester.tap(find.byKey(actionKey));
  await tester.pump();

  expect(find.byKey(actionKey), findsOneWidget);
  expect(tapped, isTrue); <- failes
});
```

```
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: true
  Actual: <false>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate of widget works for me.

```
InkWell InkWellButton() => find
          .byKey(actionKey)
          .evaluate()
          .first
          .widget;
```

and then action on Inkwell works.

```
InkWellButton().onTap();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: seems to only work for Inkwells, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try Waiting after tapping for like 2 seconds.

```
      await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 2));
```

I think it should work since it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me, I set `ensureVisible()` first.

```
var foo = find.byKey(actionKey);
await tester.ensureVisible(foo); // <-- here
await tester.tap(foo);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```